# How to improve Gaussian Process Regression fit: reducing oscillations and narrowing confidence interval

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process

I’m trying to fit a model y=f(x1, x2) to some measurements using GPR. For each instance (x1i, x2i) there are two measurements of y. I’m using the following kernel:

WhiteKernel + ConstantKernel * RBF

The result is adequate but not quite right yet, there are mainly two problems:

1. The average predicted value does pass through the measured values but there is some “oscillations” overshoot/undershoot between some points. This is shown with the red arrow in the images below.
2. The 90% confidence intervals increase too much between some  measurement points. This is shown with the black arrows in the images below.

[image]

[image]

How should I specify the kernel to get better results? Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the over/undershoot issue I recommend trying the Matern kernel, it can be seen as a generalization of a RBF with an extra parameter that controls smoothness. This extra parameter very often helps in such issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With the Marten kernel the over/-undershoot issue disappeared and the confidence intervals reduced as well :)!

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure what is problem you’re trying to solve here. The prediction intervals are a *feature*, not a bug. The Gaussian process is a nonparametric, data-based model. The intervals are thin for regions where it saw enough of the data to be certain and broad for low-data regions, where it’s uncertain. The width of the interval tells you when the predictions are more precise. To make them thinner, gather more data for the regions.

Alternatively, use a parametric model that makes assumptions about the shape of the curve, hence produces intervals of more uniform width.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. OK, I can understand that I might need more data to make the CI thinner. But what about the over-/undershoot? Can I make the predictions smoother?